# Parse database for each username

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to make a database table for every single username. I see that for every username, I can add more columns in it's row, but I want to attribute a full table for each one. How can I do that?

Thanks,
Eli

Comment: It depends in how you want to create the table. Are you using SQL directly (like phpMyAdmin) to create it or are you using PHP as a middle-man? Please outline the columns titles for the relevant tables. Additionally, outline what you've already attempted either step-by-step or by providing some relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

First let me say, what you are trying to do sounds like really, really bad database design and you should rethink your idea of creating a table per user. To get help for this you should add way more detail about the reasoning to your question to get a good answer. As far as I know there is also a maximum number of classes you can create on Parse so sooner or later you will run into problems, either performance wise or due to technical limitations of the platform.

That being said, you can use the [Schema API](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#schemas-adding-a-schema) to programmatically create/delete/update tables of your Parse app. It always requires the master key, so doing this from the client side is not recommended for security reasons. You could put this into a Cloud Code function for example and call this one from your app/admin tool to create a new table for a user on the fly or delete a table of a user.

Again, better don't do it and think about a better way to design your database, it would be out of scope here to discuss it.

Comment: Thanks, so lets say I'm trying to make an app where each user can offer rides, like blablacar.com. So i want that for every user, if he offers ride/s I can display them in the users activity. So it's not really a table for each user, but every user needs to have it's own database which will hold it's rides. What is the best way in your opinion?